# In android, How can i display selected data from databse in list view??? i am using sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, select

I am developing one android application.i want to display a data which is selected from database and display it in listview.first of all i had used static data for display Trainee(user) data. which is static. then after For same functionality i have use sqlite Database and register the Trainee(user) and now i want to display registered trainne's name in listview. i have just done below code. can anyone help me how to display trainee names in listview.

AddTraineeActivity.java 
This file works basic function of create trainee database and insert values of trainee:

```
package com.example.gymapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AddTraineeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
EditText fn;
EditText ln;
EditText un;
EditText pwd;
EditText pno;
EditText age;
Button btnAdd;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_managetrainee);
    fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfirstname);
    ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlastname);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edage);
    pno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphoneno);
    un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettraineeun);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpwdtrainee);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsavedata);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists trainee(firstname text, lastname text,age varchar,phoneNumber varchar,userTrainee varchar,passwordTrainee varchar)");
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
} 

public void show(String str)
{
Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v== btnAdd)
    {
        String firstname = fn.getText().toString();
        String lastname = ln.getText().toString();
        String Age = age.getText().toString();
        String phoneNumber = pno.getText().toString();
        String usernameTrainee = un.getText().toString();
        String passwordTrainee = pwd.getText().toString();
        if(firstname==null||firstname==""||firstname.length()<3)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Name.");
        }
        else if(lastname==null||lastname==""||lastname.length()<2)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Name.");
        }
        else if(Age==null||Age==""||Age.length()>3)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct Age.");
        }
        else if(phoneNumber==null||phoneNumber==""||phoneNumber.length()<10)
        {
            show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
        }
        else if(usernameTrainee==null||usernameTrainee==""||usernameTrainee.length()<4)
        {
            show("Please Enter valid User name.");
        }
        else if(passwordTrainee==null||passwordTrainee==""||passwordTrainee.length()<6)
        {
            show("Please Enter Strong Password.");
        }
        else
        {
            db.execSQL("insert into trainee values('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+Age+"','"+phoneNumber+"','"+usernameTrainee+"','"+passwordTrainee+"')");
            //i=new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
            //startActivityForResult(i, 500);
            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}`

UserListActivity.java
This file contain the code which display the trainee names in listview. but this file display static users for example,trainee1,trainee2,trainee3....trainee13.

```
package com.example.gymapp;

import com.tss.constant.Constant;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import com.example.gymapp.AddTraineeActivity;
import com.example.gymapp.dao.DBfitguidehelper;

public class UserListActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listViewUser;
private String loggedInType ;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
    //SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    //queryBuilder.setTables(DBfitguidehelper.)
    listViewUser = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewUser);
    String[] values = new String[]{"trainee", "trainee1", "trainee2", "trainee3", "trainee4", "trainee5", "trainee6", "trainee7", "trainee8", "trainee9", "trainee10", "trainee11", "trainee12", "trainee13"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> userAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listViewUser.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    listViewUser.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewListner());
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        loggedInType = extras.getString("loggedInType");
        System.out.println("loggedInType - " + loggedInType);
    }
} 

private class ListViewListner implements OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected user is " + listViewUser.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Constant.Selected_Trainee = ""+listViewUser.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TrainerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("loggedInType", loggedInType);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "loggedInType"+loggedInType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

now i want to display name of trainees which is stored in database. can anyone help me??

Comment: A Cursor loader is the perfect choice for you.

Comment: @KristyWelsh can you tell me how to add cursor loader in my above code?? i am a beginner in android development so please help me out of this.

Comment: Go through [THIS](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how a Cursor loader can work for you, you can review the following project that I have uploaded to github: [GPS Distance Tracking](https://github.com/techartist/GPSDistanceTracking)